# Spin down of Icy Box Raid Enclosure not working

Tags: linux, backup, raid, hardware-raid, hdparm

I am running Ubuntu server 18.04 and I am using an ICY BOX IB-RD2253-U31 enclosure with two WD Black disks (no NAS disks) in RAID 1 mode (mirror).
The external enclosure is connected via USB to the Linux server. The disks are two 1TB Western Digital Black disks, connected via SATA inside the enclosure (S-ATA 6.0 Gbit/s (S-ATA 3)).

I want to put the two disks in sleep mode / spin them down with hdparm (lowest power consumption sleep mode) with `sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sdb` but the disks seem to run like nothing happened. I also tried `sudo udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb`: This causes the OS to eject the drives, but the disks are still running (I can hear them running, and a small click when shutting it off with the built-in power switch).

Is this the fault of the enclosure? And is there any way to spin down the disks completely until needed again?

Comment: You don't say how the enclosure connects to the computer (SCSI, SAS, USB, etc.) nor what the disks are (SAS, SATA, U.2, etc.)  The answer will likely be quite different for each combination (e.g. `hdparm` is mainly for old IDE drives.)

Comment: @Malvineous Oh damn, sorry. The external enclosure is connected via USB to the Linux server. The disks are two 1TB Western Digital Black, connected via SATA inside the enclosure (S-ATA 6.0 Gbit/s (S-ATA 3)). I will update the question as well. Thank you for the hint :)

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with SATA disks over USB (this is more a question for the Linux Stackexchange rather than here on Serverfault, as most commercial servers won't be using USB enclosures) however you can try investigating `smartctl` to see if that works over USB bridges.  Last time I looked at this the limiting factor was whether the USB enclosure passed along the power management messages or not.  If you could connect it via eSATA instead then normal commands would probably work.

Comment: Thanks! I asked at Unix/Linux StackExchange before I actually asked here, but nobody responded, unfortunately. Unluckily, I cannot connect via eSata, because the mini server I am using only has USB3. Thanks for the hint with smartctl, I will check it out. Maybe on some smartctl mailing list, somebody has an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Raisonic Support for  ICY BOX IB-RD2253-U31: Standby is not supported
And it is also not working for Windows10.